# Which branch is filtered on for `pull_request` events when setting up a workflow using Github Actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to run a build for each pull request (PR) on the branch from which the PR originates, whenever a specific branch is being targeted. How do I set this up using Github Actions?

What confuses me is two branches are involved: the branch from which the PR originates, and the target branch.

From the [documentation on `pull_request` events](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull-request-event-pull_request) it is clear that `GITHUB_REF` is set to the "PR merge branch", meaning that the [checkout action](https://github.com/actions/checkout) will check out the branch from which the pull request originates in case the `pull_request` event is triggered.

But, it is less clear which branch the 'branches' filter of `on` filters on. Would the following event trigger when a PR is received on develop, or when it originates from it (or possibly, both)? How do I set up a trigger for PRs *to* a specific branch?

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - develop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the above (on pull_request branches develop) and set it up as a workflow on GitHub.

It worked as I intended to set it up. This makes me conclude that the 'branches' filter thus filters on the *target branch*.